# Additive homomorphic encryption over small fields

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Are there encryption schemes that are additively homomorphic with respect to small fields such as $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}$ or $\mathbb{F}_{2^8}$?

Comment: Do you mean where ciphertexts are in those fields or the plaintext would be constrained to being within the field and all mathematical operations are in it as well?

Comment: I meant the plaintexts are in a small field.

Comment: That is equivalent to xor-homomorphic encryption of bits - Just let the ciphertext be the ordered tuple, such as a 4-tuple or an 8-tuple, of encryptions of the plaintext's bits. ​ ​

Comment: Suppose that Player 1 wants to compute $f(ab)$, where  he holds $f(a)$ and $f(b); a,b \in \mathbb{F_{2^k}}$. Player 1 doesn't have the private key. But he can use the help of  Player 2 who posses the private key and also he Player 1 needs to prevent from Player 2 to know  the values $a$ nor $b$. @RickyDemer is it possible to implement this scheme with your suggestion? Thanks.